# How to use an abbreviated month with Zend_Date and locale formatting

Tags: zend-framework, locale, zend-date

I'm trying to set a long date format with an abbreviated month that uses the locale of the user.  Here's what I have now.

```
//getDateTimeObject('field') grabs a Zend_Date object of the field
$creationDate = $this->getDateTimeObject('objectCreated');
$creationDate->get(Zend_Date::DATE_LONG)
```

That produces the appropriate dates.    For en_US, "September 27, 2012".  For en_GB, "27 September 2012".  The problem is I need it to use the abbreviated month: en_US "Sept 27, 2012" and en_GB "27 Sept 2012".

How can I respect the locale and use an abbreviated month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $creationDate->get(Zend_Date::DATE_MEDIUM);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had checked [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html), but didn't notice the example formats were based on Germany.  I guess their medium format uses the digit vs a month abbreviation.